# Add dnorm line to Histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I follow some classes in DataCamp about R and sometimes when I replicate the code from datacamp to R-studio, I have issues but usually, I find the answer here or generally online. However, this time I cannot understand what is the mistake or how to fix it. When I run the following code to R-studio to add the line to the histogram I get too many lines instead of a single line that I got in Datacamp. This is the code:

```
library(qrmdata)

# Load DJ index
data("DJ")

DJX <- diff(log(DJ))["2008/2009"]
djx <- unclass(DJX)

# Calculate average and standard deviation of djx
mu <- mean(djx)
sigma <- sd(djx)

# Plot histogram of djx
hist(djx, nclass = 20, probability = TRUE)

# Add the normal density as a red line to histogram
lines(djx, dnorm(djx, mean = mu, sd = sigma), col = "red")
```

This how it should come according to Datacamp

[image: datacamp]

And this is what I get when I run the code in R-studio

[image: r]

Can anybody tell me what is the mistake I make?

Comment: You need to sort `djx`.

Comment: I think the problem is that your `dnorm` points are not sorted, try to sort `djx` and the corresponding `dnorm` in ascending order and you should be able to get rid of random jumping lines.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The histogram plot shows your data already sorted, whereas `lines` won't. So you have to sort your data first.

```
lines(sort(djx), dnorm(sort(djx), mean=mu, sd=sigma), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That was indeed.